# How to add a JSON column in MySQL with Rails 5 Migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, c9.io

I'm trying to add a json column in MySQL db by running:

```
class AddStatisticsToPlayerStatistic < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
       add_column :player_statistics, :statistics, :json
    end
end
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to run rake db:migrate

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `player_statistics` ADD `statistics` json
```

Does anyone know how to add a JSON column in MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53. properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL 5.5... from the docs JSON native data type starts from 5.7 - [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Comment: I was so blind I've already updated to MySQL 5.7 and it's working.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I made my comment the answer

Comment: PostgreSQL is a great alternative to MySQL and offers more datatypes including JSON, JSONB and Hstore. These datatypes all supported by the PostgreSQL adapter. Here is some more information about it: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL docs says that JSON native data type starts from 5.7.8 - [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Comment: This sintaxis worked perfectly when I upgraded my MySQL server.