# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json' rails migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mariadb

#### Error

> rails aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `lessons` ADD `image_lessons` json

#### version

```
% mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.7-MariaDB, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

#### migrate file

```
class AddImageLessonsToLessons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :lessons, :image_lessons, :json
  end
end
```

#### reference

[How to add a JSON column in MySQL with Rails 5 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313166/how-to-add-a-json-column-in-mysql-with-rails-5-migration)

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102

I think the mariadb support json. How to fix the error?

Comment: From the blog post... "adds a range on JSON supporting functions, even though **a JSON datatype isn't implemented yet**".

Comment: @dbugger oh, JSON supporting functions only! thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[I got the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646712/mariadb-server-version-for-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-json-rails-migrate#comment78260171_45646712)

> From the blog post... "adds a range on JSON supporting functions, even though a JSON datatype isn't implemented yet".